# Power off monitor -> apps closed

Tags: 17.10

if I power off the monitor, when I turn it back on I have to login again and all the apps I had opened are no closed ( like after rebooting )
How to disable that?

What I want is , my apps to stay active (  e.g. downloading a file ) when i power off the monitor!

I tried Privace > Screen Lock > off and power > blank screen > never and power > automatic suspend > off.

*Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Did you find a fix?  It's amazing this is the default behavior.  Seriously, when did ubuntu become total crap?

Comment: Looks like I am not the only one) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1757960

Comment: i actually use i3 window manager now and that doesn't happen anymore. Although i 've got another problem now. My screen goes black after some minutes of inactivity but anyways, i'm going to install arch so i dont really care